# Problems with Implementing SVM in CVX - lagrange variables alpha are not what I expected

Tags: svm, matlab, optimization

I am implementing the dual problem SVM in CVX with soft margin, and a polynomial Kernel. I have read through the theory and know that for data points crossing the margin, I should get alpha = C (1 in my case), and moreover, if I have a relatively separable data set, I should get most of the alphas = 0. However what i get is a vector of

1.0e-03 *

```
0.0012
0.0044
0.0016
0.0051
0.0059
0.0009
0.0025
0.0061
0.0031
0.0006
0.0011
0.0065
0.0062
0.0110
0.0169
0.0006
0.0209
0.0028
0.0080
0.0066
0.0024
0.0085
```

this. Basically, I cannot distinguish which alphas are 0 and which are not, and moreover, I cannot find any alphas that are equal to C (1 in my case), and I know for a fact that my data is not completely separable. If anyone has implemented the dual soft-margin SVM problem in CVX please help. Thank you so much!

---

Per the suggestion below, I have added my code.

```
% parameters
C = 100;
m = size(X,1);
n = size(Y,2);

% define Kernel matrix
Q = zeros(m,m);
for i = 1:size(Q,1)
     for j = 1:size(Q,2)
        % polynomial kernel degree 2
        Q(i,j) = Y(i).*Y(j).*(2 + 50.*(X(i,:)*X(j,:)').^2);
        % original kernel
        % Q(i,j) = Y(i).*Y(j).*(X(i,:)*X(j,:)'); 
    end
end

% train svm using cvx
cvx_begin
    variables alpha(m);
    minimize (0.5.*quad_form(alpha,Q) - ones(m,1)'*alpha);
    subject to 
        alpha >= 0;
        alpha <= C;
        Y'*alpha == 0; 
cvx_end
```

Comment: Without giving it much thought: Have you normalized your data?

Comment: We will need to see your code ...

Comment: @user11852 yes, of course!

Comment: @MarcClaesen I have edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

Define your kernel only in terms of $X_i$, that is $$Q(x_i,x_j;c,d)=(x_i^T x_j+c)^d $$

where $c,d$ are kernel parameters. Then, replace this line

```
minimize (0.5.*quad_form(alpha,Q) - ones(m,1)'*alpha);
```

with

```
minimize (0.5.*quad_form(Y.*alpha,Q) - ones(m,1)'*alpha);
```

Because the function you would like to minimize is $$L(\alpha)=  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \alpha_j y^{(i)} y^{(j)} x^{(i)T}x^{(j)} -\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$$